# Composite discriminator jpa

Tags: java, jpa, hierarchical, discriminator

I'm getting extra DTYPE in my query while my jps entities are structured as follow:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PRODUCT_TYPE")
public abstract class Product extends Tent implements Serializable {
    @@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_TYPE")
    private TransType transType;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CAR")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="CAR_TYPE") 
public class Car extends Product {

    @Column(name = "car_ent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int carEntId;
    ....
}
```

Tent
|
Product
|
**LEVEL-1** -->[Car_1_1] [car_1_2]....
|
**LEVEL-2** -->[car_2_1] [car_2_2]...

So what I'm trying to achieve, discriminate all the entities at both LEVEL-1 and 2 together. Abstract class Product is having type which discriminating immediately 1 level down but when we are further extending level 1 entities at level 2. This's where I'm not having any clue.

Can we have custom non-db field defined in Product and assigning a value to each level-1 entity and for level-2 entities TYPE can work somehow?

Not really having any clue

Thanks

Comment: Discriminator is at top level only in JPA spec

Comment: Thanks @Neil  <br> Cannot we have at multiple level to form short of composite discriminator? Or only one discriminator but having two column one is type and another one is custom which I give as per my requirement?

Comment: It looks like you misunderstood `Discriminator`. It is used to distinguish the different subclasses of an entity class. Not different entities of the same class. I guess that you don't like to create a separate class for every value of `CAR_TYPE`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that this is to discriminate entities, may be I'm not able to narrate the problem I'm facing. What I need to discriminate entities  present down the hierarchy where depth is more then 2 levels. If we take the example I mentioned in question - How I'll be able to distinguish among entities at LEVEL-2? Because all level-2 entities will be sharing same discriminate value with there parent respectively, isn't so?

Comment: just put an Enum in a Level 2 class if you need to tell those apart